# Does using typescript basically give up the prototype-based programming paradigm?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to prototype-based programming with typescirpt and found that typescript has limited support for this. So I want to know if using typescript basically gives up the prototype-based programming paradigm?

Here is my demo code:

```js
const Foo = {
  init (name: string) {
    this.name = name
    return this
  },
  getName(): string {
    return this.name
  }
}

const Bar = {
  init (name: string, label: string) {
    Foo.init.call(this, name)
    this.label = label
    return this
  },
  getLabel() {
    return this.label
  }
}
Object.setPrototypeOf(Bar, Foo)

const bar = <typeof Bar> Object.create(Bar)
bar.init('lisiur', 'javascript')
bar.getName()
```

And in the last line typescript complain that `Property 'getName' does not exist on type '{ init(name: string, label: string): any; getLabel(): any; }'.ts(2339)`. Is there a way to fix it?

---

update:

In lib.d.ts, `Object.create` and `Object.setPrototypeOf` all miss necessary type declaration(they all return any). So is there a way to declare my own `create` and `setPrototypeOf` to achieve that?

Comment: Nope. Not at all. In fact, when TypeScript is transpiled back to JavaScript, prototypes are heavily used. But, I should add, if you go that direction you should expect to be using JavaScript syntax more heavily than TypeScript.

Comment: Why are you trying so hard to avoid constructors/`class`? This implements exactly the same thing, but in a much less convenient way.

Comment: Ry is correct. Why struggle with typescript at all if you are going to lose the primary advantage it provides: familiarity (from other paradigms).

Comment: Any JS file can be renamed to be a TS file and as long as the Javascript is valid so is the Typescript (but not vise versa).

Comment: You could do `const bar = <typeof Bar & typeof Foo>Object.create(Bar)` to solve your issue, but this might not be an issue if you use JavaScript classes as others have mentioned.

Comment: @Ry- Thanks for your suggestion, but my focus is on whether typescript can do it, not whether it should be done or not :)

Comment: @RobertCooper You are right(although it is an ugly form), thanks. Now I know that typescript does lack support for prototypal inheritance.

Comment: @LisiurDay: Constructors *are* prototypal inheritance, and `class` is how you use them with TypeScript. When setting prototypes dynamically with `Object.setPrototypeOf`, declaring your intentions manually is the best you can hope for on the static side, and apparently TypeScript supports that too, so…

Comment: @Ry- I know what you mean. In fact I have doubts about the declaration of Object.create (`create(o: object | null): any;`) and Object.setPrototypeOf (`setPrototypeOf(o: any, proto: object | null): any;`). They all hide some necessary type descriptions by using `any`.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to create objects with the prototype paradigm, but TypeScript won't be able to infer their types. It is still possible to use typing but they have to be provided manually. An example:

```
interface FooBaseType {
  getName(): string
}

interface FooType extends FooBaseType {
  init(name: string): void
}

interface BarType extends FooBaseType {
  init(name: string, label: string): void
  getLabel(): string
}

const Foo = { /* … */ }
const Bar = { /* … */ }
Object.setPrototypeOf(Bar, Foo)

const bar = Object.create(Bar) as BarType // manually affects 'BarType'
bar.init('lisiur', 'javascript')
bar.getName()
```

… Or the same example, using inference from `Foo` and `Bar`:

```
const Foo = { /* … */ }
const Bar = { /* … */ }
Object.setPrototypeOf(Bar, Foo)

// Remove the following line with TypeScript 3.5
type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>

type FooBaseType = Omit<typeof Foo, "init">
type FooType = FooBaseType & Pick<typeof Foo, "init">
type BarType = FooBaseType & typeof Bar

const bar = Object.create(Bar) as BarType // manually affects 'BarType'
bar.init('lisiur', 'javascript')
bar.getName()
```